# Unable to Get a Correct Time when I am Calling serverTime using jquery.countdown.js + Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var shortly = new Date('April 9, 2010 22:38:10');
        var newTime = new Date('April 9, 2010 22:38:10');
        //for loop divid
        /// 
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
            until: shortly, onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown, serverSync: serverTime
        });
        $('#div1').countdown({ until: newTime });
    });

    function serverTime() {
        var time = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //Page Name (in which the method should be called) and method name
            url: "Default.aspx/GetTime",
            // If you want to pass parameter or data to server side function you can try line
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            async: false,
            //else If you don't want to pass any value to server side function leave the data to blank line below
            //data: "{}",  
            success: function(msg) {
                //Got the response from server and render to the client

                time = new Date(msg.d);
                alert(time);
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                time = new Date();
                alert('1');
            }
        });

        return time;

    }
    function watchCountdown() { }
    function liftOff() { }

</script>
```

```
 [WebMethod]
public static String GetTime()
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();  
   dt = Convert.ToDateTime("April 9, 2010 22:38:10");

    return dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Default.aspx/GetTime code

public static String GetTime()
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime("April 9, 2010 22:38:10");

            dt = Convert.ToDateTime("April 9, 2010 22:38:10");
   
   
    }

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609028/here-is-my-code-in-jquery-and-asp-net-unable-to-get-a-correct-ans-as-i-am-gettin and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608838/having-problem-with-jquery-countdown-function-serversync-servertime

Answer (score 0):

The return fires before the callback; you have to use the callback to set some value.  In the success or failed callback, you need to pass the date to an HTML element or assign a global variable.

HTH.

Comment: hello Brian

I am using first time Jquery.countdown.js

will you please give me an example

Comment: hello  Brian


  $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
                until: shortly, onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown, serverSync: serverTime
            });
    serverTime = this callback function will Init the value of variable shortly